# Saving kartik select2 widget data with a model

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii-extensions

Am using kartik select2 widget and i would like it to save data to the database by passing it to the controller.

I have tried this
1. the select2 widget

```
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>$model->formName()]); ?>
     <?php
        echo $form->field($model, 'unitid')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map($model2,'unitid','unitname'),
        'language' => 'de',
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select a Unit '],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]);
  ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

2. The javascript code to save data on form submit which is on the view:

   ```
   <?php 
     $script = <<< JS

    $('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) 
   {
   var \$form = $(this);
    console.log(\$form.serialize());
   $.post(
   \$form.attr("action"), 
   \$form.serialize()
    )
   .done(function(result) {
    console.log("Succesifully saved" + result);
     }).fail(function(err) 
      {
       console.log("failed to save" + err);
      });
     return false;
     });
     JS;
    $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
   ```

This generates this output on the console(for the serialized form output

```
_csrf=TGMzaDRINnEHFgM5RjIPICc2bBoZAWZAOBIGAnAeVSF4GUQteThUFw%
3D%3D&Unitslocation%5Bunitid%5D=&Unitslocation%5Bunitid%5D%5B%5D=9
```

the output is always passed as a string that is after trying

```
echo json_encode($model->unitid);
```

On the controller it returns a string instead of an integer
that is

```
["5"]
```

How can i convert ($model->unitid) to integer for the post params

Comment: what is the error displayed....

Comment: It just displays failed to save [object Object]

Comment: It also displays 500 internal server problem

Comment: Then the error may have been in the controller action where you are trying to save the form data

Comment: I have seen it to be in the validation rules but after correcting it seems the $.post passes integers as strings would you know of a way i can convert the string to an integer

Comment: In php you could convert it by using $int = (int)$string;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117894/discussion-between-geoffrey-mwangi-and-mohan-rex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$model->unitid = (int) $model->unitid;
```

Thats all.